# different synchronized() parameters producing differnt answers

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the difference between
`synchronized(classname.class)` vs `synchronized(this)` vs `synchronized(AnyObjectName)`?
Why all three produces different answers, when synchronized block requires just any object?

Comment: They don't produce *answers* at all - they acquire monitors, but they'll acquire different monitors because they're different references. You need to be a *lot* clearer in what you're asking.

Comment: when I just put an increment operator inside these three classes, they should produce the same result

Comment: That's still not enough information. We don't know whether you've got several threads trying to increment the same variable which may or may not be guarded by each synchronized block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**synchronized(this)** is synchronized on the current object, so only one thread can access each instance, but different threads can access different instances. E.g. you can have one instance per thread.

**synchronized(SomeClass.class)** is synchronized on the class of the current object ( or another class if one wished) so only one thread can access any instances of that class.

**Usage of synchronized(classname.class)**

```
    public class MyClass {

        public static synchronized void log1(String msg1, String msg2){
           log.writeln(msg1);
           log.writeln(msg2);
        }


        public static void log2(String msg1, String msg2){
           synchronized(MyClass.class){
              log.writeln(msg1);
              log.writeln(msg2);  
           }
        }
   }
```

Only one thread can execute inside any of these two methods at the same time.

Had the second synchronized block been synchronized on a different object than MyClass.class, then one thread could execute inside each method at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it. By convention, a thread that needs exclusive and consistent access to an object's fields has to acquire the object's intrinsic lock before accessing them, and then release the intrinsic lock when it's done with them. A thread is said to own the intrinsic lock between the time it has acquired the lock and released the lock. As long as a thread owns an intrinsic lock, no other thread can acquire the same lock. The other thread will block when it attempts to acquire the lock.`

`When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock for that method's object and releases it when the method returns. The lock release occurs even if the return was caused by an uncaught exception.`

So, In synchronized blocks you can explicitly specify the lock. Where as in synchronized methods 'this' is the lock by default. For static synchronized methods 'CalssName.class' is the lock.

from: [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)